# How to communicate between server and android?

Tags: android, client, android-c2dm

Which is better way to send messages from server (Java) to android client? Comet, socket, xmpp or something else? I'm going to develop simple client-server game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Android Cloud to Device Messaging](https://code.google.com/android/c2dm/index.html) might work for your needs if you are sending lightweight messages to the device where timing isn't so important. If you need a long-lived connection for transmitting game data then you probably want to use Java sockets in the [java.net package](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/package-summary.html).

Comment: I think socket connection is the best way. Thank you.